# java + MQ chunk keeps increasing

Tags: ibm-mq

I have a situation where 1 batch from  branch is at the pre-processing queue.

The number of records is only 700 but the chunk keeps increasing.
What can be the problem?
I would appreciate it if you could advise what I should check.

Comment: could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question to include the relevant source code and configuration information; at the moment the community doesn't have a lot to go on, making it less likely that anyone will pick your question up. It would probably also be good to tag your question as java, given that the java element is important enough for you to have put it in the title. Thanks.

Comment: What does this question have to do with IBM MQ?